# 3d city database set up problem

Tags: spatial-database, 3d, citygml

I am trying to set up 3d city database and I have some problems. I hope you can help me. I receive an error as you can see attaching file. What is wrong?[image: attaching picture]

The error message is:

```
'"\psql"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

and results from this command:

```
C:\long_path\PostgreSQL\SQLScripts>"\psql" -d "3dcitydb PGBIN=C:\Program files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin" -f "CREATE_DB.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **PGBIN** variable correctly in your CREATE_DB.bat script. It needs to point to the path containing the psql.exe.

In my case it looks like the following:

`set PGBIN=set PGBIN=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin`

Hope that helps!

Comment: It might be helpful to put the path in quotation marks, since it contains a blank.